# Jenkins warnings-plugin does not find C warning

Tags: c, jenkins

I've just installed the nice warnings plugin for an avr-gcc project, and configured it to scan the source as well as the console for warnings.
I've put an unused variable on purpose and in the console I have:

```
lambda.c: In function ‘display’:
lambda.c:59:6: warning: unused variable ‘unused’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int unused = 0;
      ^
```

But the plugin does not find the warning:

```
[WARNINGS] Parsing warnings in files '**/*.c, **/*.h' with parser GNU Make + GNU C Compiler (gcc)
[WARNINGS] Finding all files that match the pattern **/*.c, **/*.h
[WARNINGS] Parsing 3 files in /home/dode/.jenkins/jobs/lambda/workspace
[WARNINGS] Successfully parsed file /home/dode/.jenkins/jobs/lambda/workspace/lambda/lambda.c with 0 unique warnings and 0 duplicates.
```

Am I using the wrong parser or what did I miss?

Comment: Why don't you rely on `gcc`'s warnings? and if you could use `clang` then you would have more warnings.

Comment: It is not that I don't rely on gcc's warnings, but I want to use Jenkins for CI and have a failing build if there are (too many) warnings.

Comment: Downvoter - could you please explain what is wrong with my question?

Comment: i am facing a similar problem. What i noticed, if i redirect the compiler output to a file and add this file to the warnings plugin it detects the warnings. I guess one of the recent jenkins updates broke parsing of the consle output